# Why does recursive function "infinite" loop return same number

Tags: php, loops, memory

I wrote this recursive function in php, to try on various servers:

```
<?php
  $a = 1;
  function tryit($num){
    echo $num.'<br>';
    $num++;
    tryit($num);
  }
  tryit($a);
```

On one server it stops at 24773 each time and the other stops at around 18179 each time. Both are well within the max_execution_time of 30 seconds: they run for around a second.

Why does execution stop at those points?

Comment: You're probably running into a stack size limit.

Comment: What do you mean by _return same number_? Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file(s) and tell us if you get any: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, it needs to store its local variables, and also the information on how to continue execution after it ends, somewhere. For that it uses a so-called "Call-stack", which is limited. The limit just happens to be different on two of your machines.

See more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack